# How do these results show that $T(\mathbf{X})$ is an unbiased estimator of $E_\varphi[T(\mathbf{X})]$ that achieves the Cramer-Rao lower bound?

Tags: estimators, unbiased-estimator, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family, cramer-rao

Let's say that $X_1, \dots, X_n$ has the joint distribution $f_\varphi(\mathbf{x})$ that belongs to the one-parameter exponential family

$$f_\varphi(\mathbf{x}) = \exp{\left\{ c(\varphi) T(\mathbf{x}) + d(\varphi) + s(\mathbf{x}) \right\}},$$

where $\mathbf{x} \in \text{supp}(f_\varphi)$, $\text{supp}(f_\varphi)$ does not depend on $\varphi$, and $c^\prime(\varphi)$ is continuous and does not vanish.

I am told that the results

$$E_\varphi [T(\mathbf{X})] = - \dfrac{d^\prime (\varphi)}{c^\prime(\varphi)}$$

and

$$\text{Var}_\varphi [T(\mathbf{X})] = \dfrac{c^ {\prime \prime}(\varphi) d^\prime(\varphi) - c^\prime(\varphi)d^{\prime \prime}(\varphi)}{c^\prime(\varphi)^3}$$

can be used to show that $T(\mathbf{X})$ is an unbiased estimator of $E_\varphi[T(\mathbf{X})]$ that achieves the Cramer-Rao lower bound. However, it is not at all clear to me how this is done. How do the results $E_\varphi [T(\mathbf{X})] = - \dfrac{d^\prime (\varphi)}{c^\prime(\varphi)}$ and $\text{Var}_\varphi [T(\mathbf{X})] = \dfrac{c^ {\prime \prime}(\varphi) d^\prime(\varphi) - c^\prime(\varphi)d^{\prime \prime}(\varphi)}{c^\prime(\varphi)^3}$ show that $T(\mathbf{X})$ is an unbiased estimator of $E_\varphi[T(\mathbf{X})]$ that achieves the Cramer-Rao lower bound?

Comment: Simultaneous cross-post yet again: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4133132/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **unbiasedness** part holds trivially from the fact that you have stipulated that the unknown quantity you are estimating is the expected value of the estimator.  Denoting this by the parameter $\theta \equiv \mathbb{E}_\varphi(T(\mathbf{X}))$ and noting that your estimator is $\hat{\theta} \equiv T(\mathbf{X})$, you then clearly have:

$$\text{Bias}(\hat{\theta}, \theta) = \mathbb{E}_\varphi(T(\mathbf{X})) - \theta = \mathbb{E}_\varphi(T(\mathbf{X}))-\mathbb{E}_\varphi(T(\mathbf{X})) = 0.$$

So, it remains only to show that this estimator is **efficient** (i.e., it achieves the [Cramér-Rao lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound)).  To do this, we first observe that the [Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) function for the distribution is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(\varphi) 
&= -\mathbb{E}_\varphi \Bigg( \frac{d^2}{d\varphi^2} \log f_\varphi(\mathbf{x}) \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= -\mathbb{E}_\varphi \Bigg( \frac{d^2}{d\varphi^2} [c(\varphi) T(\mathbf{x}) + d(\varphi) + s(\mathbf{x})] \Bigg) \\[6pt]
&= -\mathbb{E}_\varphi \Bigg( c''(\varphi) T(\mathbf{x}) + d''(\varphi) \Bigg) \\[12pt]
&= - c''(\varphi) \mathbb{E}_\varphi(T(\mathbf{x})) + d''(\varphi) \\[12pt]
&= \frac{c''(\varphi) d'(\varphi) - c'(\varphi) d''(\varphi)}{c'(\varphi)}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

(The final step here comes from substituting $\mathbb{E}_\varphi(T(\mathbf{x})) = - d'(\varphi)/c'(\varphi)$.)  The corresponding information function for $\theta$ (still framed in terms of the parameter $\varphi$) is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}_\theta(\varphi) 
&= \mathcal{I}(\varphi) \Bigg/ \Bigg( \frac{d \theta}{d \varphi}(\varphi) \Bigg)^2 \\[6pt]
&= \frac{c''(\varphi) d'(\varphi) - c'(\varphi) d''(\varphi)}{c'(\varphi)} \Bigg/ \Bigg( \frac{c''(\varphi) d'(\varphi) - c'(\varphi) d''(\varphi)}{c'(\varphi)^2} \Bigg)^2 \\[6pt]
&= \frac{c'(\varphi)^3}{c''(\varphi) d'(\varphi) - c'(\varphi) d''(\varphi)}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Consequently, the efficiency of the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is:

$$\begin{align}
\text{Eff}(\hat{\theta}, \theta)
&\equiv \frac{1}{\mathcal{I}_\theta(\varphi)} \Bigg/ \mathbb{V}(\hat{\theta}) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{c''(\varphi) d'(\varphi) - c'(\varphi) d''(\varphi)}{c'(\varphi)^3} \Bigg/ \frac{c''(\varphi) d'(\varphi) - c'(\varphi) d''(\varphi)}{c'(\varphi)^3} \\[6pt]
&= 1. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

This establishes that the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is an efficient estimator for $\theta$ (i.e., it achieves the Cramér-Rao lower bound), which completes the demonstration.